# Unable to provide CLASSPATH in docker?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, docker

**Problem:**

I am facing a **classNotFoundException** when i try to connect jsp container to mysql container by running an web application(.html, .jsp files) in browser.

**Note:** It is executing as expected in Eclipse

**Description:**

I have created an "mysqlrep" image using below dockerfile and i am using this image name in docker-compose.

```
from ubuntu:14.04
run apt-get update
run apt-get install mysql-server -y
run apt-get install curl -y
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
env set MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= root
add my.sql /var/lib/mysql
run bash -c "/etc/init.d/mysql start && mysql -u root </var/lib/mysql/my.sql"
```

In above dockerfile, i created database using my.sql file as shown below

```
CREATE SCHEMA softwareag;
use softwareag;
create table users(
  username varchar(10) primary key,
  pwd varchar(10),
  fname varchar(10),
  lname varchar(10), 
  email varchar(30)
);
insert into users values('shashank','shas','shashank','g','sg@gmail.com');

CREATE USER "root"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "root";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "root"@"%";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml where i am linking mysql container and jsp container

```
mysql:
   image: mysqlrep1
   container_name: mysqlcompose1
   environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= root
   ports:
       - "0.0.0.0:3306:3306"
   command: bash -c "/etc/init.d/mysql start && cd /var/lib/mysql && mysql -u root && sleep 50"

jsp:
   build: .
   container_name: jspcompose1
   links:
     - mysql
   cap_add:
     - SYS_PTRACE
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   command: bash -c "/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start &&  ping 127.0.0.1 -c 100"
```

i am creating an jsp container in docker-compose using dockerfile. Inside dockerfile, using ubuntu as the base image and installing jdk, tomcat7 on top of it and mounted .html, .jsp files inside /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT directory of jsp container.

**Note:** i also tried many syntax to set the classpath for mysql .jar file after adding mysql .jar to lib directories inside dockerfile but it doesnt solve my issue.

After running docker-compose up, at the same time i am accessing it in browser through http://system-ip-address:8080/index.html.

**Note:** In index .html, user click submit button after he enters his username & password, it redirects to signIn.jsp page to verify username/password by connecting to mysql database.

It works but when user click submit, it get redirected to signIn.jsp where it throws ClassNotFoundException.

This is my signIn.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Sign In</title>
  </head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>

<%
 try{
  String userid=request.getParameter("usr"); 
  session.setAttribute("username",userid); 
  String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   java.sql.Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/softwareag","root","root"); 
   Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users where username='"+userid+"'");
   if(rs.next()) 
   { 
     if(rs.getString(2).equals(pwd)) 
     { 
     response.sendRedirect("http://www.softwareag.com/in/");
     }
   }else
   {
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/index.html");
   }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      out.print("Exception:"+e);
}
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Can you suggest the solution to make it work ?**

**How and where to provide classpath for mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar file ?**

Comment: You have to place the JAR file either to `WEB-INF/lib` of your web application, or to the Tomcat's `lib` folder (in your case `/var/lib/tomcat7/lib`).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek It's gotta be in Tomcat's `lib` directory if you want Tomcat to load it. @Shashank's origin question shows manually-creating a JDBC connection, but he doesn't really want to do that. Not really.

Comment: Where is your MySQL JDBC JAR file on the disk? Can you arrange to put it anywhere you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I run the docker images which start tomcat8 server but it don't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581793/i-run-the-docker-images-which-start-tomcat8-server-but-it-dont-start)

Comment: Hey.. Did you get solution?? I have a simple Java application and I need to set classpath and add the jar to the application..